# Is it possible to load JAR to your running Java application on the fly?

Tags: java, classloader

I have plugin system in my Java application. Is it possible to load JAR / Java classes on the fly to your application, or do I have to include these JAR / Java classes to my application?

My idea was to load plugin to application and then call interface method of this class, without need to restart Java application. Is this possible or even wise at all?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd recommend to use OSGi for dynamic plugin loading / unloading. It handles all the class loading stuff. If you cannot use OSGi, you'll have to use own class loaders and configure them with the location of your to-be-loaded jar files.

Answer (score 4):

You can, by employing your own ClassLoader which locates the JAR file and returns the class bytes to the JVM. Have a look at this tutorial from sun: http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Security/Fundamentals/magercises/ClassLoader/help.html

Answer (score 4):

I'd also recommend OSGi, but for a simpler plugin based system, check out the java plugin framework.  It aims to simplify plugin based systems and can be found at http://jpf.sourceforge.net/.

As @Liv mentioned, something like a URLClassLoader can be used for simple, one-off, loads, but it's a quick fix, not a good starting point for a plugin loading system.